# Why can't I use REST Web App while SOAP web app is on the same Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, soap

I have a Tomcat 8.0 server with a REST api in the webapps folder (activiti-rest). I could make successful REST calls to it until I made a SOAP project using JAX-WS and placed the JAX-WS jars into the Tomcat libs folder. The SOAP service works but now the REST api keeps returning 404 errors. What's the problem or how can I even find out the problem? The log files in Tomcat are barebones, only giving the URL and error code.

Comment: What about the ports the applications are using?

Comment: have you modified your web.xml file (or using the Java based WebApplicationInitializer)?

Comment: What is the servlet mapping for both? What is the URL pattern? URL pattern should be different for both. e.g. For rest something like /rest/* and for soap something like /soap/*